# Is there any way to check the iOS crashes logs ? Didn't receive in logcat and Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter, testflight

App is getting Crash. When I check the log file, I did not receive an appropriate log. Facing trouble from the last 2 days. I Tried checking log file on daily basis even Checked crashes on the Testflight.

Is there any other way to check the iOS crashes logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on the device inside Settings > Privacy & Security > Analytics & Improvements > Analytics Data > look for any crash logs with titles containing your app's name (this is for  iOS 16.5.1).

Alternatively you can connect the device to a macOS computer, open Xcode, open Devices & Simulators, and click "View Device Logs".